# to_latex: Incorrect Encoding for Strings (with Backslashes)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` `df` that looks like this:

```
|      A      | B | ... |
-------------------------
|    a\b\c    | 2 | ... |
|    p\y\c    | 9 | ... |
|    a\d\x    | 4 | ... |
```

Calling `to_latex` on this `DataFrame` returns strings like `a\textbackslashb\textbackslashc`, what obviously is an error for LaTeX.

Are there any options or common encoding strategies for this?

**Edit:** Using `escape=False` returns `a\b\c` what is also an error for LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood the question. Reopened now.

Comment: So, the to_latex() translates the data frame with the `...`? You are saving it to a file? Does it still appear with the ... then?

Comment: ``pandas`` has a ``max_colwidth``, every string longer than that gets truncated when displayed (including ``to_latex``). So it's possible that a string ``a\b\c\d\c\d\c\d``, if long enough, gets truncated to something like ``a\b\c\d\c\d\...``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seemed to be a bug, I've created an issue and a pull request that got merged into the master and will be part of the next release (0.23.0).

It can handle now cases like `a\b\c`, the special chars `^` and `~` were also affected.

For more information see [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/20860).